# Setting a structure to auto-away

Tags: java, nest-api

I am using the nest firebase libraries, and can successfully set structures to "away" and "home", however, setting the structure to "auto-away" doesn't seem to have any effect.  Does the nest api not allow for setting structures to auto-away, only moving them out of auto-away? This would be a needed feature. I have a system that can detect when people leave, but not (accurately) when they return, so setting the nest to auto-away so it will turn on when they return is my goal.

Working:

```
nestFirebase.child(path).setValue("away");
```

Failing:

```
nestFirebase.child(path).setValue("auto-away");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto away is determined and set by the structure/thermostat itself using various algorithms based on signals such as presence among others. 
The Nest API only lets you read the status of auto-away. While writing, the only allowed valid values are either 'away' or 'home'

Comment: You can't do that by design is not the answer is was hoping for :( It would really be a good choice to allow such behavior. 3rd party apps could really make good use of it.